# Will compiled queries be effective when parameters change for same query everytime?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am new to entity framework. I am using a linq query that will fetch many records (upto millions) from database. There are many filter parameters in where condition and on each request the parameters may change. So i wanted to know whether compiled queries will be effective in this case or will it be a new query on each request. Here is my query:

```
List<FarmerDetailsReport> fdr = 
(from fp in mstfp join pd in personalDetails on fp.personDetails.Id equals pd.Id
join ic in identityCertificate on fp.identityCertificate.Id equals ic.Id 
join pid in pacsInsuranceData on fp.pacsInsuranceData.Id equals pid.Id into temp
from pid in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join bd in bankDetails on fp.bankDetails.Id equals bd.Id
join cd in contactDetails on fp.contactDetails.Id equals cd.Id
join id in incomeDetails on fp.incomeDetails.Id equals id.Id into tmp
from id in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join ua in userAttributes on fp.UserId equals ua.EmailID 

where ((ua.CompanyName == companyName ) && (cd.District == model.DistrictForProfileMIS ) && (cd.Block == model.BlockForProfileMIS) && (bd.bankName == model.BankForProfileMIS ) && Status == "Active")

select new FarmerDetailsReport { .......... }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer:*

Yes...... well, maybe.

*Long answer:*

This is hard to answer as you have no control over the actual SQL that gets generated.

We had perf problems with some queries like this as the optimizer would optimize for a certain wet of filter cases (like short circuits of clauses) then when a new query was made with a massive change in parameters it would take AGES.

What we did in the end:

1. Don't use a big LINQ query, create a stored proc or view where you have more control over the SQL generated.
2. Used things like `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` ... looks this up it was very useful.
3. Have a few overloads of the query for different parameters so that the DB can optimize them separately.

Obviously this is just what we did, it might not be perfect for you. I STRONGLY suggest getting the generated SQL for each different parametrized version and going over it with your DBA (if you have one) or your team and google if you don't.